# try-catch block giving compilation error

Tags: java, try-catch

I am trying to add some of my code in try-catch block, but it fails at compilation and I am not getting what is wrong.

```
try 
{ 
    int x = 0; 
    int y = 5 / x; 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Exception"); 
} 
catch (ArithmeticException ae) 
{
    System.out.println(" Arithmetic Exception"); 
} 
System.out.println("finished");
```

Can anybody help please.

Comment: While this issue was easily caught, in the future it is helpful if you tell us what the actual error message your receiving is.  Other issues may be more complicated and without the error message, it can sometimes be anyone's guess.  No one knows more about your code than your compiler.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use :

```
try 
{ 
    int x = 0; 
    int y = 5 / x; 
} 
catch (ArithmeticException ae) 
{
    System.out.println(" Arithmetic Exception"); 
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    System.out.println("Exception"); 
} 

System.out.println("finished");
```

While handling exceptions, wider exceptions(super class exception, in your case Exception is super class of ArthmeticException) must be catch after catching sub-class exceptions. Otherwise, exception will be caught by wider/parent exception catch block and latter code will be unreachable. So it will not compile.

Comment: To clarify on this answer, it is because the general Exception catch will always be called before anything below it, so you shouldn't catch that first (Generally, you shouldn't catch general exceptions anyhow). Edit: sneaky edits!

Answer (score 4):

exception hierearchy says

```
ONCE YOU HAVE CAUGHT AN EXCEPTION IT NEEDS NOT TO BE CAUGHT AGAIN
```

since you already are catching Exception in your first catch block

thus your next catch block is useless

you should catch child classes first , then for the remaining possible other exception should catch parent Exception class

try this

```
try 
{ 
    // your code throwing exception
} 
catch (ArithmeticException ae) 
{
    // do something
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: +1 for "ONCE YOU HAVE CAUGHT AN EXCEPTION IT NEEDS NOT TO BE CAUGHT AGAIN" line :)